# TS2693: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: typescript, node.js-typeorm

so as not to repeat the code, I would like to create an abstract class once, which will connect to the appropriate repository depending on the initialization of the class with the appropriate type T. However, I have a problem that I don't know how to call the value T and not the type as a parameter of the getRepository method from typeorm package.

```
import {getDataSource} from "../utils/data-source";
import {Category} from "../model/category";
import {EntityTarget, ObjectLiteral} from "typeorm";

export abstract class Controller<T> {
    protected repository;

    public init = async () => {
        this.repository = (await getDataSource()).getRepository(T);
    };
}
```

getRepository(T);
this method has the problem mentioned in the title

Comment: "I don't know how to call the value T" there is no value `T`.

Comment: The error is telling you exactly the problem - `T` doesn't exist at runtime, it's just a type.

Comment: Types are erased before the code can be run, so you cannot change runtime behavior simply by changing a type.

Comment: You need to make getDataSource() generic in order to achieve that. As answered above by @GuillaumeBrunerie, T is just a type and is not available at runtime

Answer (score -1):

This is the easiest way to do it, if there isn't a better one

```
import {getDataSource} from "../utils/data-source";

export abstract class Controller {
    protected repository;

    public init = async (type) => {
        this.repository = (await getDataSource()).getRepository(type);
    };
}
```